# Change the size of UILabel or the font to fit in Accented Character

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, frame, sizetofit

I have a UILabel with Text inside it called :

```
self.textLabel;
```

Now, I noticed that whenever I added an accented letter like Ä Ö Ü, then I get an effect like :

[image]

Notice how the top dots on the accented letters are cut off. I want to get the text to fit the label, however the `self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2` constraint which ensures that I have 2 lines and the text after the sentence goes beyond the width is maintained. Essentially, I want a label like :

[image]

With the dots maintained. Now, I have tried :

`[self.frame sizeToFit]` which does not work because it wraps around the entire text. As I said, cut the text out after 2 lines.

Using `.bounds` and `CGRectMake` to create new frames and then assign their new height to the current frame, which doesn't work either. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948714/adjust-size-of-uilabel-to-fit-height-of-text for more information. Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was to do

```
self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

And then doing :

```
[self.textLabel sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding top padding to label fixed the issue for me.

```
@IBDesignable class PaddingLabel: UILabel {

@IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 5.0
@IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 0
@IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 0
@IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 0

override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
    super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let size = super.intrinsicContentSize
    return CGSize(width: size.width + leftInset + rightInset,
                  height: size.height + topInset + bottomInset)
}   

override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
        // ensures this works within stack views if multi-line
        preferredMaxLayoutWidth = bounds.width - (leftInset + rightInset)
    }
} 
}
```